# trigger a release build of Jenkins using a plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to do build promotion in Jenkins as follows:

- Jenkins job A build prod A snapshot
- A has downstream job B which deploys A snapshot to Test env.
- B has a downstream job C which runs test on Prod A in Test env.
- If C is successful, I would like to promote job A by kicking of a release build of job A; 
  this will kick off job B which will deploy release version to Prod env ;Job C will get kicked off to run tests on Prod env.
  If C is successful just send mail to all.. it should not kick off another build of A.

Am trying to use the build promotion plugin where I can set the criteria.

1. But in the Actions section how can I kick off a release build of A.?
   Also note that the first round is snapshot build of A. When C is successful, I want to trigger a release build of A just once. It should not keep going in a loop.
2. If you have any other better ideas to achieve this functionality, please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use **two job chains**:

1. one set of jobs A/B/C for snapshot (say, `A-snap`/`B-snap`/`C-snap`), and
2. another set of jobs A/B/C for release (e.g., `A-rel`/`B-rel`/`C-rel`).

Configure **promotion of `A-snap`** so that it will **trigger `A-rel`**. Do not use promotion for `A-rel` (or use a different action for handling successful releases). **This will prevent the "loop problem"** that you mentioned.

**Duplicating the jobs appears awkward in the first place, but** will be simple when using some framework for generating jobs automatically (like the [Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin)). On the other hand, **you'll end up with a much clearer setup**, as you will avoid that the *same* job actually performs *different* tasks (here: snapshot- and release-related build/deployment/test). **This has additional benefits:**

- snapshot and release tasks can run in **parallel** (if you have the resources)
- if the build job is tied to **SCM**, then mixing snapshot/release builds would result in a mess (bad changelogs, wrong blaming)
- even when not tied to SCM, **traceability will be much better** when not mixing snapshot/release builds in one and the same job.

Regarding your question "1.": actually triggering `A-rel` will be simple (there's `Build other projects` action). You need to ensure, though, that `A-rel` will run on the same snapshot version that is currently being promoted.